# Restart after power Failure with FSCK?

Tags: power, failure, fsck

Is there any way to have a Raspberry automatically after a power failure?

This is a great feature on Mac OS X that I would like to have on my Pi because of it's usage.

It would also be great if I could trigger a file system check and repair during boot after a power failure.

What say you Stack Geniuses? Can I do either?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Raspbian you can get fsck to run automatically on reboot when necessary by adding `FSCKFIX=yes` to `/etc/default/rcS`

Comment: Thanks @Keyvan! That's awesome.

Now I just need it to restart automatically when power is restored!